# Updating the data in webapp without showing it on screen

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to create an app that will be used in android (maybe iOS) using html5, css3, javascript (phonegap,cordova and node.js is being used)

I currently have external source which I use HTTP request to grab data, which I use Rgraph to plot it in chart. However, I realized that when I reload/reopen it, it recreates the graph.

I was wondering if there is anyway to update the app in certain time interval without having the app displayed on my smartphone screen (using my current setup)?

I have another way which does not require the update, but I wanted to update in background because one of my other feature requires time interval update.

Comment: Would AJAX be suitable for your app?

Comment: I believe I am using a bit of ajax (I am quite new to this...) but how could ajax fix the problem?